# Installer built by Inno Setup and SPAWNWND, NOTIFYWND parameters on UAC window

Tags: inno-setup, uac

What are `SPAWNWND` and `NOTIFYWND` parameters in the program path?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those two parameters are used for communication between the elevated and non elevated parts of the setup for `...AsOriginalUser` functionality, exit codes, etc.
You can probably find more details in the [Inno source code itself](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc).

Note that these are an implementation detail and you shouldn't rely on them or do anything with the values.

Answer (score -2):

`spawn()` is a c-function group that executes, child processes, but not through a forking! There is `spawnvl()` - vl stands for "variable list" of arguments (like `spawnvl(arg1, arg2, arg3,...arg n, NULL);`). `spawnl()` I guess executes a program with fixed amount of arguments in a list. There are also `spawnvle()` and `spawnle()` - these are similar to `(int argc, char **argV)` - the `e` stands for environment, that means the `argv-char` array, and again they exist with variable and fixed amount list args. Linux equivalents are `exec -function` group.

I guess these functions (processes invoked) communicate via `signals` to their parents

Comment: It's probably better if you don't post without reading the question and taking a look at the tags it includes. This question is specifically related to InnoSetup, and it has absolutely nothing to do with C or the `spawn()` group of functions. InnoSetup is written entirely in Delphi, and does not use the spawn function or any of its relatives.